# Line plot error with ggplot2 and geom_line

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the code below which produces errors like:

```
In geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = mean) :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `fun.y`
```

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = friend_count), data = pf) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(13,90)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.05,
             position = position_jitter(h = 0),
             color = 'orange') +
  coord_trans(y = "sqrt") +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .1)) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = .9))
```

RStudio's linter isn't happy about `probs` in the `list()` either.

I'd appreciate any help. All the googling I did led to this solution which isn't working.

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Comment: Hey, can you add example data to go along with so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Try `stat_summary(geom = "line")` instead of `geom_line(stat = "summary")`.

Comment: Also note, `fun.y` is deprecated — instead just use `fun`, and if the results aren’t correct add `orientation = "y"`. See [`?stat_summary`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html).

Comment: Actually, your original code should work too if you just change `fun.y` to `fun`.

Comment: Thank you @zephryl. That did the trick (fun instead of fun.y) Much appreciated.